# javascript doesn't work in web app

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I'm developing an android app using phonegap. I created a favorite section on my app and I use `localstorage` to set a value of file name to 1 . Then I created a page named fav.html and I set the `display` value of my list to `none` like this :

```html
<ul class="table-view">
 <li class="table-view-cell" style="display: none;">
<a class="navigate-left padder" href="modele1.html" data-transition="slide-in" >item1</a>
 </li>
 <li class="table-view-cell" style="display: none;">
<a class="navigate-left padder" href="modele2.html" data-transition="slide-in" >item2</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Than I used a javascript code like this to change the `display` value to `block`

```js
<script>
    if (localStorage.getItem("modele1.html")==1){document.getElementsByClassName("table-view-cell")[0].style.display = 'block';}
    if (localStorage.getItem("modele2.html")==1){document.getElementsByClassName("table-view-cell")[1].style.display = 'block';}
</script>
```

I already checked and `localstorage` value for `modele1.html` and `modele2.html` is set to `1` . The code works fine on chrome but when I build the code with phonegap the script doesn't work. I even added the script manually to my end of `fav.html` before the `</body>` tag and rebuild the app but it still doesn't work on the phone? Please help me this is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well finally i found the problem. i use `fileName = location.pathname.substring(1);` code to store the key of localstorage value. in windows the full address of file was `/modele1.html` so this code return file name but in phonegap the full address of file was `/android_assets/www/modele1.html` . so obviously i needed to change the code to `fileName = location.pathname.substring(19);` and Vola problem solved :)

Comment: Please mark this as an [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) then for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but one thing that occurred to me was that you aren't waiting for *deviceready* event. This might be required for Cordova but not for Chrome since Cordova needs to load the implementation during boot and Chrome already has it available. Try this

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    // alert("deviceready event");
    if (localStorage.getItem("modele1.html")==1) {
        // alert("1");
        document.getElementsByClassName("table-view-cell")[0].style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("modele2.html")==1){
        // alert("2");
        document.getElementsByClassName("table-view-cell")[1].style.display = 'block';
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

If it still doesn't work as you intended, you can uncomment the alerts to see if the execution reaches there.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tried the code and still it doesn't work. excution only reaches the device ready alert